# How fix this JSON parse error in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have created a Restfull service with Spring, just a simple sing-up API to sing-up an admin user:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signupAdmin(@RequestBody Admin admin){
        if(adminRepository.existsById(admin.getUsername())){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Username already taken", HttpStatus.FOUND);
        }else{
            adminRepository.save((Admin) admin);
            return new ResponseEntity<Admin>( adminRepository.findByUsername(admin.getUsername()), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

Here the code, with missed Getters and Setters:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class User {
    @Id
    protected String username;
    protected String email;
    protected String password;
}

@Entity
public class Admin extends User{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Survey> created_survey;
}

@Entity
public class Customer extends User{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Choice> choices;
}
```

I have tried a lot, but i can't fix that, here is the json to be parsed with Admin

```
{username: "aaa", email: "aaa@", password: "aaa", created_survey: []}
```

And this is this is the error:

```
POST "/admin/signup", parameters={}

Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.modal.Admin> com.controller.LoginController.signupAdmin(com.modal.Admin)

Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.modal.Admin> com.controller.LoginController.signupAdmin(com.modal.Admin): JSON parse error:Cannot deserialize instance of `com.modal.Admin` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.modal.Admin` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.modal.Admin` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.modal.Admin` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]

Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

Maybe subclasses don't inherit fields.
I know it's hard to find a way to solve this error, i hope someone can just help me

### SOLVED

```
let user = {"username": "user", "email":"email", "password":"password"};
http = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
http.send(user); //WRONG
```

How i solved it

```
let user = {"username": "user", "email":"email", "password":"password"};
http = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
http.send(JSON.stringify(user)); //CORRECT
```

I don't know why JSON.stringify is necessary, but it works

Comment: This is because your JSON is not valid. You can check this using any online JSON validator. Here is a corrected version of your JSON snippet:
`{
 "username": "aaa",
 "email": "aaa@",
 "password": "aaa",
 "created_survey": []
}`

Comment: can you add Survey entity and Array(0) actual value

Comment: @MarianoCaldara My Bad, I had hoped for an easy answer. Sorry, as I am not a subject matter expert ... can't help then. I will delete my answer, and wish all the best that someone else figures what is going on.

Comment: { "username": "aaa", "email": "aaa@", "password": "aaa", "created_survey": [] } just send it from PostMan and it go, but when do it from my React App on js, it returns error 400 :(

Comment: And you are sure that react sends the same JSON String?

Comment: Just solved, look up